# Boundary of Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I am having a really difficult time understanding boundary points, closures, and boundaries of sets in topological spaces.

For example, I cannot figure out the following problem:

> Describe the boundaries of the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (with the subspace topology):
>
> 1. $(0,1)$
> 2. $\mathbb{Z}$
> 3. $\left\lbrace\frac{1}{n}\:|\:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\rbrace$, and
> 4. $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

I know that the boundary is the intersection of the closure and the closure of the complement, but I am really lost other than that. I think limit points are really difficult for me to understand. How should I do this problem?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A. S. Hopkins:  I've edited your question in a manner that I think makes it a bit easier to read (and it is going to be easier to address the four sets if we give them numbers ;).  If I have somehow ruined your question, please rollback my edits.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ you need to find the boundaries with respect to the usual metric?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Yes, with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Two questions. Do you know how to write down complements of those sets and do you know how to determine closure?

Comment: @Ennar No, I am completely lost.

Comment: Not even complements? Complement of $A$ in $X$ is defined as $X\setminus A$, i.e. a set of all points in $X$ that are not in $A$. For how to determine closure, it would be good if you included what you do know about closed sets and closure.

Comment: The boundaries of those sets with the subspace topology are empty.  The boundaries of those subsets of R with the usual topology are not empty.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary is the **intersection** of the closure and the closure of the complement. This means that $x$ is in the boundary of $A$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ (however small) contains points both of $A$ and the complement of $A$.

The boundary of $(0,1)$ is indeed $\{0, 1\}$. Any point inside $(0,1)$ has a small neighbourhood that lies totally inside $(0,1)$ and any point $x > 1$ or $x < 0$ has a small neighbourhood that satisfies the same condition (all of the sets $(0,1)$, $(1,\rightarrow)$ ,$(\leftarrow, 0)$ are open in the reals). But a small neighbourhood $(-r,r)$ of $0$ will contain points of $(0,1)$ (like $\frac{r}{2}$) and points not in $(0,1)$ (like $-\frac{r}{2}$). So $0$ is a boundary point and $1$ goes the same way.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the mistake you pointed out and fixed it. So how would we rigorously show what the boundary of $(0,1)$ is? Is it just $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Yes it is. First, show that if $x = 0$ or $x = 1$ then $x$ is a boundary point (by considering arbitrary neighbourhoods of $x$. Then, if $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$, then find a neighbourhood of $x$ which is contained entirely in $A$ or entirely in $\mathbb{R} - A$.

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*

Use this relation:

$\partial{A}=\bar{A}$ \ $A^o$

where $\partial{A}$ denotes the boundary of the set $A$

Comment: I use this method as well. For one thing, it makes it clear that, when a set has no interior, its boundary is simply its closure.

Comment: Indeed it is usefull sometimes